# Script to return a value on a specific cell if other cell content meets criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison

I'm just getting started with Google scripts and I'm trying to create a very basic script to help me understand the fundamentals.

The script would look for the number 5 in cell E2 and then return a value of 5 if true or 10 if false. 
The issue I'm running into is that if I enter a `5` on E2 I do not get a `5` on E4. it always says `10` on E4.

I have tried changing the operator to `=` and `===` as well as putting quotes (`"5"`) around the `5` to look for text rather than a number and can't get it to work.

```
function onEdit()
{

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange(2,5);
var cell2 = sheet.getRange(4,5);


  if (cell == 5) {cell2.setValue(5);}
  else {cell2.setValue(10);}


}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Would you please tag what language you are using.

Comment: Certainly and thanks

Comment: For the future: [tag:google-apps-script] is the main tag you need for these questions. Java is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in comparison `cell == 5`. It should be `cell.getValue() == 5`.

Indeed, `cell` is an object that abstractly represents the cell: by calling one its methods, you can change its value, or make the background red, or set data validation, etc. `getValue` is one of these methods, which returns the value contained in the cell.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. That is the part that I was missing. Thanks a lot